# How can I create custom forms for shopify and mail the informations to another email address?

Tags: javascript, forms, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Im kinda new to Shopify Development and got stuck at some point. We want to implement a form which the user can fill and after the submit button, we want just to mail all the informations from the form to another email, which is not saved in the store informations.

I already searched for some apps but didnt found a good one. I also tried to implement a php script but seems like shopify dont like it.

*We also got MailChimp just for Info.